# How to check Self Referencing cell formula in excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there any way to find out Self Referencing cell formula in excel using OpenXML C#. I didn't recognize how to find out Self Referencing cell formula. For e.g Cell C3 has formula **=SUM(C1:C5)**. How to recognize this formula had self Referencing cell? or Can I can get all cell names from this formula?
My code is:

```
SpreadsheetDocument excelDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true);    
WorkbookPart wbPart = excelDocument.WorkbookPart;
string sheetId = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First().Id;
WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(sheetId));
IEnumerable<Cell> theCells = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>();
foreach (Cell thecell in theCells)
{     
  string strFormula = thecell.CellFormula.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: I would guess that there is no one-stop way to do this as cell references can be quite obscure (through indirection). Does it have to be 100% accurate or is it okay if the code only detects some cases of self-referencing formulas and not all?

Comment: Yes it will, if the code only detects self-referencing from some cases. Will you help me with this?

Comment: Looking at the documentation it does not seem like there is any help from the API. I haven't run anything though. If I were you, I'd see whether the cell formula has any child nodes (probably not). If not, in all likelihood, there is no built-in way. Then you can still do string based analysis. I would first rule out numbers and functions (easy to find, as numbers don't start with letters and functions have parenthesis), then you can look for cells and ranges, and lastly you match for each cell and range found whether they equal/contain itself